# Are WSE asmx web services supported on Windows Server 2008?

Tags: web-services, windows-server-2008, asmx, wse

We have asmx web services created in WSE. Now if we upgrade our environmenet from Windows Server 2003 to Windows Server 2008, will the services keep working ?

Any work around if they are not supported directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, WSE asmx web services are not supported on Win2k8 server.

Comment: In fact, WSE is obsolete, should be replaced by WCF services and clients as soon as possible, and should not be used for new development unless there are no other choices at all.